# typo3 create double root page

Tags: typo3, backend

I'm new to typo3 and I just came across through a backend of a certain website and found two issues. Why there are two duplicated root pages within the same website as shown on the picture attached? How can I create something like this?[typo3 backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AiuK.png)

Comment: those pages have different IDs? you can discover the ID placing the mouse pointer on the page icon for some seconds.
Another way: edit your user and in TSConfig field put `options.pageTree.showPageIdWithTitle=1`

Comment: Hello Riccardo thanks for your reply. The IDs are the same for both root pages ID=1.Not only that even IDs for the sub pages are the same or in other words the root pages are duplication of each other there is no any difference between them.

Comment: I suppose that you are facing some weird bug due to a configuration error of your user. Is it an administrator?
If it is an administrator, edit it and check the field "DB Mounts": if it has the Home page,  remove it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with the db_mountpoints in your usergroups.

Have a look at the database table "be_users" and the field "db_mountpoints". If there is a usergroup which has the value "0" it will lead to the problem you have.

If a usergroup should not have a db_mountpoint the value must be "null" not "0".